# Trigger Drupal Rule Based on Taxonomy Term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules

I have a rule built that sends an email to users of a specific role, when new, published content is created. What I want to do is be able to send this email only when the content matches a specific taxonomy term. Unfortunately, I'm struggling with this -- any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you say the content "matches" the term, do you mean the content has a field to select that term, and you want the email to send when the content has been tagged with that term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say the content "matches" the term, do you mean the content has a field to select that term, and you want the email to send when the content has been tagged with that term?

If thats the case...

1. Create a new condition "Entity Has Field"
2. Choose the **taxonomy field**.
3. Create a new condition "if **taxonomy field** == taxonomy name"
4. Create action to send mail to user of a role.